# How can i know the hard disk name?

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, fdisk

How can I find the name of the hard disk I'm already in as I tried

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

but the result contains a lot of names, i just need the hard disk I'm using now , please

EDIT

I got

```
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   1.8T  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   3.7T  0 part /data
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the hard disk I am using"? Depending on what you are doing, the answer could be different.

Comment: i'm using a computer remotely but i don't know which drive I'm using i just create an account and using it remotely

Comment: It depends on what you strictly mean with name and _in_. Some commands to get info about "first disk" is `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda`, `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda` or `inxi --disk-full`. Seems [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), why do you need this info? You already know [all this](https://www.howtogeek.com/137096/6-ways-the-linux-file-system-is-different-from-the-windows-file-system/)?

Comment: i need to recover the files i deleted from the trash and I'm using the computer remotely. so i need to specify which drive i need to check or recover it

Comment: I like Gnome Disks which comes with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

"The harddisk I'm using now" might depend on which folder you are in, even `$HOME` might be on a separate disk from `/`, entrily dependent on how the disk was set up.

Does this answer your question?

```
$ lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 931,5G  0 part 
sdb           8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
...
```

This might pinpoint what you're after, one line selected from above.

```
$ lsblk | grep ' /$'
```

Another peek:ing to do

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by*
... (loads of text)
```

Comment: Thanks please can you see the edit post , i posted the result i got but i couldn't identify which hard disk I'm using now

Comment: add the output of `$ pwd` and compare the results,

Comment: Most likely /dev/sda if you have not done `cd /Data` or similar

Comment: i got from pwd `/home/sam/`

Comment: As lsblk does not have a `/home` entry you are on  `/` in the subfolder `sam` under `home`  -> `/dev/sda2`

Comment: excuse me i'm confused so this is the drive I'm on `─sda2` ?

Comment: yes, The disk is  `/dev/sda` and the second partition, so `/dev/sda2`

Comment: please is there any way to check it or ensure that is the drive

Comment: The filesystem (ext4fs; the driver) provides access to filenames, folders and storage space administration. e.g. `/home/sam/` (the $HOME folder) and `/usr/bin/lsblk` which you just ran a minute ago

Comment: The above ensures it.